# Universal Image Loader does not load Duplicate Images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am trying to load images from web service in my android application. I can load images using Universal Image Loader Library. But the problem I am facing now is that it does not display duplicate images while loading images in my list view.

Comment: Are you fetching duplicate image from cache ? I think you have to verify if Univaersal Image Loader is falls check to load duplicate image from RunTimeCache i.e LRUCache

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: I think this explains well the cause https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/681#issuecomment-48843454